# Can we find and $R$ such that the following condition holds?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $f(z) = \frac{ z e^{iz} }{z^4 + 1}$. For every $\epsilon > 0$, can we find an $R(\epsilon) > 0$ such that $|f(z)|< \epsilon $ whenever $|z| > R(\epsilon) $ ?

My attempt: since $|a+b| \geq |a|-|b| $, we have

$$|f| = \frac{ |z e^{iz} |}{|z^4 + 1|} \leq \frac{ |z| |e^{iz}| }{|z|^4-1} \leq  \frac{ |z| |e^{iz}| }{|z|^4} \leq \frac{ |e^{iz}|}{|z|^3} \leq \frac{1}{|z|^3} $$

and so as long as $|z| \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\epsilon}} = R(\epsilon)$, we have our result. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not correct because $| e^{iz} | = 1 $ holds only for *real*
numbers $z$:
$$
| e^{iz} | = | e^{i(x+iy)} | = | e^{ix - y} | = | e^{ix} | |e^{-y}| = e^{-y} \, .
$$

And since
$$
|f(-iy)| = \frac{y e^y}{y^4+1} \to \infty \text{ for } y \to +\infty
$$
such an $R(\epsilon)$ can not exist.

If $z$ is restricted to the upper halfplane then $| e^{iz} | < 1 $
and therefore (with $R = |z|$)
$$
|f(z)| \le \frac{ |z | }{|z^4 + 1|} \le \frac{|z  |}{|z^4| - 1} = \frac {R}{R^4 - 1}
\to 0 \text{ for } R \to \infty \tag{*}
$$
and therefore for every $\epsilon > 0$ you can find an $R(\epsilon) > 0$ such that $|f(z)|< \epsilon $ whenever $|z| > R(\epsilon) $.

If you want an *explicit* formula for $R(\epsilon) $
then you can (for example) estimate the right-hand side of $(*)$
as follows: For $R \ge 2$, $R^4 - 1 > \frac 12 R^4$ and therefore
$$
\frac {R}{R^4 - 1} < \frac {R}{\frac 12 R^4} = \frac{2}{R^3} < \frac 1R
$$
so that $|f(z)|< \epsilon $ for  $|z| > R(\epsilon) := \min (2, \frac 1\epsilon)$.

Comment: But, what about if we only consider the upper half plane ?

Comment: Then $| e^{iz} | < 1 $. There is still a small error because omitting $-1$ in the denominator makes the fraction *smaller* but that can be fixed.

Comment: So, to fix this, should I do $|z^4 + 1 | \geq 1 - |z|^4$ instead ?

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy: See updated answer. Of course that is only one possible (and not very precise) estimate.